# Azure Maps Template animation not working

Tags: javascript, html, azure, azure-maps

I'm trying to use this template but the animation doesnt quite work. eveything is being plotted but after clicking "play" it doesn't move.

The only thing i changed was the subscriptionKey

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/AzureMapsCodeSamples/blob/master/AzureMapsCodeSamples/Animations/Animate%20along%20a%20path.html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvuhP.png)

Comment: Have you looked at the console for any errors? I suspect the input file isn't be read by the fetch API if you are running this locally.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the example on a local computer or on the server, you have to include the js library of the animations

```
<script src = "../ Common / scripts / azure-maps-animations.min.js"> </script>
```

[source  javascript](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/AzureMapsCodeSamples/blob/master/AzureMapsCodeSamples/Common/scripts/azure-maps-animations.min.js)